# I want to generate file hierarchy using file path only in java.

Tags: android, file, hierarchy, filepath, file-handling

I am new to android. I have database which maintains file path. Now i have to show file hierarchy like file manager in list view . I need to display name only in list view of application. No need to display file in that listview.

Answer (score 0):

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html

You can follow the url to manage file hierarchy like file manager in list view .